# Lastname, firstname switch

Tags: sql

Please help, I'm not at all good with SQL but I have created the query below. It pulls information from a room booking system to display on a digital signage product.

At present the 'Name' field outputs as `lastname, firstname`. I really need it to display as `Firstname Lastname` but still under the one column.

Can someone take a look please? It would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    HOST9006.DESCRIPTION, 
    HOST0110.ROOMNAME, 
    HOST0140.NAME, 
    dateadd(mi, HOST0120.STARTMINS, HOST0120.MTGDATE) AS ASTART, 
    dateadd(mi, HOST0120.ENDMINS, HOST0120.MTGDATE) AS AFINISH, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(mi, HOST0120.STARTMINS, HOST0120.MTGDATE) ,108) AS START, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(mi, HOST0120.ENDMINS, HOST0120.MTGDATE) ,108) AS FINISH, 
    HOST0120.MTGKEY, HOST0120.HIPTYPE, HOST0120.ROOMKEY
FROM 
    HOST0140
    INNER JOIN HOST0120
    ON HOST0120.OWNERKEY=HOST0140.PERSONKEY
    INNER JOIN HOST9006
    ON HOST9006.KEYVALUE=HOST0120.MTGSTATE
    INNER JOIN HOST0110
    ON HOST0110.ROOMKEY=HOST0120.ROOMKEY
WHERE 
    CANCELSTATE='0'
AND MTGDATE >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND MTGDATE < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
AND MTGSTATE <> '11'
ORDER BY START
```

Thanks

Comment: Give your question a **meaningful** title

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started for sql-server (you did not specify what RDBMS you are using):

```
select substring(col1, charindex(',', replace(col1, ' ', '')) + 1, len(col1)) 
  + ' ' 
  + left(col1, charindex(',', col1) -1) as First_Last
from names
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20c7d/27)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for mySQL

```
select concat(right(Name, length(Name) - instr(Name, ',') - 1),
' ',
left(Name, instr(Name,',')-1))
from mytable
```